# Make array in rails show only numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an array I'm building like this:

```
Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => 2).select(:id).inspect.to_a
```

when I print the variable I get this:

```
[#<Post id: 70>, #<Post id: 44>]
```

I would like it to be:

```
[70, 44]
```

What I should be doing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => 2).select(:id).map(&:id)
```

The reason it's still good to keep the select statement in there is that it reduces the amount of data you are returning from the database. Even though the same statement will work without the explicit select, it's more efficient to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => 2).map {|p| p.id }
```